# node.js command works in terminal but fails in npm

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, nodemon, yarnpkg

I have got a really weird issue. I have just updated all the dev dependencies in my project and it has broken my `dev:server` script. Now when running it with npm or yarn I get this:

```
npm run dev:server

> my-proj@0.0.0 dev:server C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\my-proj
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development concurrently "tsc -w --project ./server" "nodemon server"

[2] 'server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2] operable program or batch file.
[2] server exited with code 1
[0] Version 2.2.2
[0] Syntax:   tsc [options] [file ...]
[0]
[0]
[0] Examples: tsc hello.ts
[0]           tsc --outFile file.js file.ts
[0]           tsc @args.txt
[0]
[0] Options:
[0]  --allowJs                                          Allow javascript files to be compiled.
[0]  --allowSyntheticDefaultImports      
...
```

`tsc` seems to be complaining because it doesn't understand that it should use the server directory which has its own tscofig file.

But when investigating I found that running `cross-env NODE_ENV=development concurrently "tsc -w --project ./server" "nodemon server"` in the exact same terminal worked fine? Which suggests this is an npm or yarn bug, however nither of those have been updated and it seems very unlikely that they have both suddenly developed the same bug!

Any ideas?

NB: I am using Windows

Comment: Can you post package.json, or at least scripts section?

Comment: @ahz the relevant task is `"dev:server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development concurrently \"tsc -w -p ./server\" \"nodemon server\"",`

Comment: Do you have `scripts.start` in your `package.json`? If so, what it is? Does it work when you remove either the `tsc` or the `nodemon` processes from the command string?

Comment: Posting your full package.json (or at least all 'scripts', 'dependencies' and 'devdependencies') might help get to the root of the problem

Answer (score 0):

`cross-env` was updated to version 4.0.0 recently.

```
npm info cross-env | grep -B4 "4.0.0':"
 '3.2.2': '2017-03-04T16:13:55.420Z',
 '3.2.3': '2017-03-04T16:44:27.226Z',
 '3.2.4': '2017-03-14T16:24:01.735Z',
 '4.0.0-beta.0': '2017-03-27T01:51:04.557Z',
 '4.0.0': '2017-03-31T02:07:49.386Z' },
```

You mentioned the problem happened after upgrading your dev dependencies. Is `cross-env` a dev dependency? Is this one of the dependencies that you updated?
If you downgrade it, does your script start working again?

I tried find a recent change that might cause the error you see, but couldn't say for definite. Maybe this one https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env/commit/ea8002130477f044e66508179394eea485583b2a